# Oblique asymptotes by long division

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Due to my horrid ability with long division I have an extremely hard time finding the oblique asymptote for any function.

In the problem given I am required to find the oblique asymptote for$$y = \frac{x^3}{x^2-x}$$

I have found that the asymptote is $x+1$ from looking online. But I am required to show how I came to the answer, I have not been able to do this as I do not understand long division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use a workaround. Notice that
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{x^3}{x^2-x}
 &= \frac{x^3 - x^2}{x^2-x} + \frac{x^2}{x^2-x} \\
 &= \frac{x^3 - x^2}{x^2-x} + \frac{x^2-x}{x^2-x} + \frac{x}{x^2-x}\\
 &= \frac{x^2(x - 1)}{x(x-1)} + 1 + \frac{1}{x-1}\\
 &= x + 1 + \frac{1}{x-1} \\
\end{split}
$$

Comment: What is the format that you used for determining the answer, as I think I understand how you got the answer. But I would like to make sure that I understand the formatting before applying it to other equations.

Comment: @Miki i don't understand -- are you asking how did i know whcih simplifications to make? If so, you just fit the numerator to be $x^n$ times the denominator until it fits for $n \ge 0$

Comment: It took me a while to understand this so hopefully this helps anyone else googling: Split the equation up into parts, e.x. (x^2-3x+2)/(x+2) = (x^2)/(x+2) - (3x)/(x-2) + 2/(x+2) and then make the top part of the equation be a multiple of the bottom by adding. Ex. (x^2-4)/(x+2) - (3x+6)/(x+2) + (2+4-6)/(x+2) and then simplify. There's the asymptote (x-5, ignore the remainder). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $y=\frac{x^2-1+1}{x-1}=x+1+\frac{1}{x-1}$. So

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-(x+1))=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x-1}=0$$

$y=x+1$ is an oblique asymptote.